# Implementation of Gradient-Reversal-layer into a functioning keras model for multiclassification

Tags: python, tensorflow, machine-learning, keras

My question is about the practical implementation of "Domain Adaptation" into a functional model in keras with tensorflow backend.

**Description of the problem:**

I have a collection of particle collision samples which consist of n variables. One half of them is simulated data with certain class labels (e.g "W-Boson"). The other half is real collision data which is not labeled. The key idea now is to setup a keras model, which has two outputs. One for classifying the class of a sample and one for classifying the domain, so wether it is simulated or real data. The thing is that the model shall be trained so that the domain classifier performs very poor. This is achieved by flipping the sign of the incoming gradient from the domain end of the network during training. This technique is called "Domain Adaptation". The model is expected to be trained to find domain-invariant features, or in other words, to perform the same on simulated and real collision data.

The framework I am working with has an existin functional keras model, which I wanted to expand with said domain classifier. This is a prototype I came up with:

```
# common layers
inputs = keras.Input(shape=(n_variables, )) 
X      = layers.Dense(units=50, activation="relu")(inputs)

# domain end
flip_layer = flipGradientTF.GradientReversal(hp_lambda=0.3)(X)
X_domain   = layers.Dense(units=50, activation="relu")(flip_layer)
domain_out = layers.Dense(units=2, activation="softmax", name="domain_out")(X_domain)

# class end
X_class    = layers.Dense(units=50, activation="relu")(X)
class_out  = layers.Dense(units=n_classes, activation="softmax", name="class_out")(X_class)
```

The code for `flipGradientTF` is taken from https://github.com/michetonu/gradient_reversal_keras_tf

And further on for compiling and training the model:

```
model = keras.Model(inputs=inputs, outputs=[class_out, domain_out])
model.compile(optimizer="adam", loss=loss_function, metrics="accuracy")

# train model
model.fit(
    x             = train_data, 
    y             = [train_class_labels, train_domain_labels], 
    batch_size    = 200, 
    epochs        = 200, 
    sample_weight = {"class_out": class_weights, "domain_out": None}
)
```

For `train_data` I am passing the dataframe which consists of the data from both domains. As I have tried to use either "categorical_crossentropy" or "sparse_categorical_crossentropy" as the `loss_function`, `train_class_labels` and `train_domain_labels` where either in the one-hot representation or in the integer representation. My biggest issue is figuring out what to use for the class labels of the unlabeled data and this led to a gut feeling that I am on the wrong track here.

So in a nutshell:

**Is this implementation strategy legit and assuming it is, what should I do about the class labels for the unlabeled data? And if it is not legit, what would be a better way of attacking this problem?**

Any help would be much appreciated :)

Comment: I'm tyring to do the same implementation. What is `train_domain_labels` in your code? Regarding your question, I believe it depends on the approach: supervised vs unsupervised DA. There is no label/class for unlabeled data (=unsupervised DA). However, I still don't know how the coding should be done for that to work.